# fetching data from database and sort it and display it

Tags: cakephp

I have a database containing details of the products purchased by many persons. just like shopping cart.so I have to display the details of all persons who have purchased the products according to the date of purchase. I have an order_date field in the database. i want to know the query for displaying the data in the sorted order.please help me.

```
public function get_orders{ 
    return $this->find('all',array('order'=>array('Order.order_date DESC'))); 
}
```

this is my model named Order. in controller I call this function using

```
$order=$this->Order->get_orders();
```

and display using for each loop

Comment: my order by query is not working. here is my query

Comment: array('order' => array('Article.created DESC')))

Comment: try like this `array('order' => array('Article.created' => 'DESC')));`

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have a model of name `Product` and then in your controller put this code to get the products in descending order.

```
$this->Product->find('all', array(
    'order' => array('Product.order_date' => 'DESC')
));
```

**Update:**

```
public function get_orders{ 
    return $this->find('all',array('order'=>array('Order.order_date' => 'DESC'))); 
}
```

**(OR)**

```
 public function get_orders{ 
      return $this->find('all',array('order'=> 'Order.order_date DESC'))); 
 }
```

For more info you can check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find).

Comment: public function get_orders{ return $this->find('all',array('order'=>array('Order.order_date DESC'))); } this is my model named Order. in controller I call this function using $order=$this->Order->get_orders(); and display using for each loop

Comment: For your info, I've just used `Product` as an example here.

Comment: let me know if you are getting any problem in the above.